# printf() not working before do while loop

Tags: c, eclipse, codeblocks

I tried to ran this code :

```
printf("Enter a character.");
printf("\n");

do {
    ch = getch();
    system("cls");
    putchar(ch);
} while(ch != '.');
```

The above code works fine on **Codeblocks** but it is not working on **Eclipse** IDE. In fact the `printf` statement before `do while` loop is not working, but if I disable `do while` statement the printf statement working fine on eclipse. Could you explain why is this happening ?

Comment: Try adding a `fflush(stdout)` before the loop

Comment: A program running under Eclipse doesn't necessarily behave the same as running the program directly from the command line because the standard I/O channels are not normally perceived as being 'interactive devices' (terminals), so the output becomes fully buffered, and there is no automatic flushing of standard output before input from standard input (which is not guaranteed by the C standard anyway, though most implementations do flush standard output before reading standard input when the output device is a terminal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this?

```
printf("Enter a character.\n");
fflush(stdout);

do {
    ch = getch();
    system("cls");
    putchar(ch);
} while(ch != '.');
```

I think it's because your output buffer (printf) is not flushed.

Comment: What makes certain IDES flush the output buffer without having to write fflush (codeblocks) ,and other IDES you need to manually add fflush (eclipse)?

Comment: I think the translation of code from high/low-level language to machine language varies from compiler to compiler some use techniques that others don't as not all compilers are constructed the same.

Comment: Sorry by compiler you mean the IDE right? Because both codeblocks and eclipse use gcc as a compiler I think. Which is why I'm confused that in one IDE, you don't need to put fflush,while in the other one you do.

Comment: It's to do with the 'terminal window' in which the program is run.